# Handling a Docusign Rest api exception?

Tags: docusignapi

I want to know if this is possible: I would like to have a custom text field on an envelope that I set and if the envelope fails for some reason, like there are missing tabs or email address is bad, I want to be able to look at the exception and see the custom field that I set. Would this info be in the raw data? It is as important to us to know which envelopes failed as to know why they failed. I saved the custom field in a database before sending out the envelope. When it fails, I can look up that custom field and discover which envelope didn't make it and to take some action, like correcting and resending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If the envelope is created incorrectly (i.e: specifying a conditional parent tab which does not exist, syntax error, etc), then you will know at the time you attempt to create the envelope w/the API. The reason will be included in an error code the API returns
- If an envelope was sent to an email address which does not exist/bounces, that information can be discovered using the DS API to see a recipient/envelope status of 'autoresponded', or if you are using DS Connect you can receive a push notification.

Is there additional rationale why you want to use a custom field? Per the above, I do not believe it is necessary or applicable.

Comment: We will be sending out envelopes that are tied to a particular account in our system. So we need to know if an envelope fails, which account was this particular envelope attached to so that we can take appropriate action.

Answer (score 0):

With the RestSharp api, I was able to get the Request body. The Request body has a collection of Parameters, and one of those items is the RequestBody.